# on click of a link increment php variable

Tags: php

I have a button that I would like to increase a number by 1 and reload the page when clicked. If the user navigates away from the page and then comes back i would like the number to be reset to 0.

any ideas how this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's how you could do it if you're wanting to change up what image is displayed. Pretend this url is your page:
http://someserver.com/photo_page.php?photo_id=1

The photo id is the thing you're wanting to increment. You can get at this via the $_GET superglobal.

So, quick off the top of my head example:

```
$my_var = $_GET['photo_id'];
$next_photo = $my_var + 1;
$the_link_i_want_to_make_my_button = 'http://someserver.com/photo_page.php?photo_id='. $next_photo;
```

You'd then put that link as what your next button does, and you would default it to 1 or whatever you want if `empty($_GET['photo_id'])`.

Also probably want to make sure that you handle people putting silly numbers in there like 9000 if you have over 9000 images, etc.

I think this'll get you close?

Comment: What i want to do is, currently my page displays an image retrieved from a database when the user clicks the next button i need it to increase a number which corresponds to the number currently being displayed. basically so a new image is displayed

Comment: Oh, so this is like a photo gallery? Why don't you just store the id as part of the URL? I'll edit the previous with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just increment it after the page reload? If it absolutely has to be done, you would have to do it with an AJAX call.

Comment: I would like the variable to be reset if the user navigates away from the page and the process starts again if they come back and press the link

Comment: Button (html input or button element) != link (html hyperlink). Which is it?